# How to grep for repeated patterns of repeated patterns?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, pcregrep

I have a text file, fred.txt:

```
% cat -e fred.txt 
00:$
00:04:$
01:00:23:34$
01:$
01:40:$
01:40:32:$
%
```

I can grep for a line with 2 digits and a colon:

```
% pcregrep -e '[\d]{2}:' fred.txt   
00:
00:04:
01:00:23:34
01:
01:40:
01:40:32:
%
```

but when I try to get repeating patterns of that pattern, it doesn't find them:

```
% pcregrep -e '[[\d]{2}:]{2}' fred.txt
%
```

I'm looking to get the same output as this:

```
% pcregrep -e '[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:' fred.txt
00:04:
01:00:23:34
01:40:
01:40:32:
%
```

Eventually I'll be looking for more nested repeating patterns in a larger file so I don't want to define each time the pattern repeats. How do I grep for the lines that have that pattern repeating?

Comment: I think you're confused by the brackets. There's no point in `[\d]`, that's the same as `\d`. The `[ ]` are used to define a character class, but `\d` is already a character class so you don't need to put it in `[ ]` unless you combine it with something else like `[\dabc]`. Then, as shown by [schrodigerscatcuriosity's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/689034/22222), you group things with parentheses `(foo){2}` and not square brackets `[foo]{2}`.

Comment: That’s what I didn’t understand. Most of my complex regex use has been in Sublime Text so I’m not proficient outside of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using GNU `grep`

```bsh
$ grep -Eo '([0-9]{2}:){2,}' fred.txt 
00:04:
01:00:23:
01:40:
01:40:32:
```

Answer (score 7):

`[xyz]` called bracket expressions is to match *one* character within a set. Here, either `x`, `y` or `z`.

`[\d]` would match either `\` or `d` in POSIX basic regexps, but in perl-compatible regexps, it matches the same as `\d` alone: a digit. That allows things like `[\da-fA-F]` to match one hex digit for instance, but in the `[\d]` case, it's pointless, as you might as well use `\d`.

In any case, it's not for grouping for which you need `\(...\)` in POSIX basic regexps or `(...)` in POSIX extended regexps or PCREs.

PCREs have a few other variants of grouping such as `(?:...)` which groups without creating a back-reference, or `(?|...)` which groups but affects how back-references are numbered in alternations, or `(?>...)` the possessive variant of the grouping operator, etc.

Here, you don't need backreferences, so you might as well use `(?:...)`:

```
pcregrep '(?:\d{2}:){2}'
```

Would match on lines that *contain* 2 of (2 digits followed by a `:`). If you wanted to match on lines that *are* e`x`actly that, you'd need to add the `-x` option.

Here,

```
pcregrep '(?:\d\d:){2}'
```

Would actually be shorter.

```
pcregrep '(\d\d:){2}'
```

Would have the same effect, but possibly be slightly less efficient as we didn't tell `pcregrep` not to bother *capturing* what's inside the `(...)`.

See `man pcrepattern` to learn more about the syntax of PCREs.

Answer (score 5):

Using `grep`

```
$ grep -Eo '([^:]*:[[:digit:]]+:?)+' input_file
00:04:
01:00:23:34
01:40:
01:40:32:
```